# Print text to crash file in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to run a build of a macOS app on a virtual machine. Currently the app is crashing at launch and there is no way for me to diagnose the problem without an output. I noticed that a crash report is generated at "/Users/User/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports".

Is there a way to "print" to the Crash Report so I could know which functions executed before the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode can not detect the cause of the crash if the crash happens before attaching the debugger.

So you may consider using the macOS built-in **Console** app to check log and activities which locates in:

```
/System/Applications/Utilities
```

[image: Launcher]

Then you can see the crash logs and other logs in a live mode :)

[Here is a quick tutorial for the **Console** app](https://www.howtogeek.com/406592/how-to-use-the-console-on-macos-to-check-log-and-activities)